# div selected with :focus disappearing when clicking a link in IE

Tags: css, css-selectors

Given two divs `box1` and `box2`, I am trying to make `box2` appear by clicking on `box1` using a `focus` selector.

Inside `box2` is a simple hyperlink which makes `box2` disappear when clicked on. This is expected since clicking on `box2` deselects `box1` and is thus no longer focused. However, in Firefox 31 and Chrome 37, the browser still takes me to the linked webpage as desired, but IE 11 does nothing.

Here's a simple jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ndwurxg2/

clicking the red box will make the grey one appear, then clicking on the link "Google" will take you there (I'm assuming jsfiddle just redirects to its own page, but you can see it is loading), whereas IE doesn't.

Is there any css only workaround to this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the only CSS solution would be to change the `visibility` to `visible` when hovering over the element too. I'm not sure if that is the behavior you are going for, but it works in IE now.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/0mzvht87/)

```
#box1:focus ~ #box2,
#box2:hover,
#box2:active {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use the following:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bvstf0qy/)

```
#box1:focus ~ #box2,
#box2:focus,
#box2:active {
    visibility: visible;
}
#box2 a:active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: for some weird reason I was originally trying to avoid this solution, but given the way my page is now set up, this works just fine. thanks!